# Как правильно оформлять методы, у которых слишком много аргументов?

Tags: java, css

Вопрос не касается оптимизации кода, которая должна привести к уменьшению количества кода. Предположим, что у нас уже есть метод и выглядит он например вот так:

```
package2.MyClassSystemName method1(MyClass1 argName1, MyClass2 argName2, AnotherClass1 argName3, AnotherClass2 argName4) {
//Некоторый код
}
```

Как его отформатировать, с точки зрения стиля Java, что бы он стал более читабельным.
Мой вариант мне кажется страшным все равно:

```
package2.MyClassSystemName method1(
    MyClass1 argName1, 
    MyClass2 argName2, 
    AnotherClass1 argName3, 
    AnotherClass2 argName4) 
{
    //Некоторый код
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language, глава 4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-136091.html)

Там написано что надо так

```
package2.MyClassSystemName method1(MyClass1 argName1, MyClass2 argName2,
        AnotherClass1 argName3, AnotherClass2 argName4) {
   ...
}
```

Написано что отступ в 8 пробелов